# Log to AppInsights from Azure Function App Startup.cs

Tags: logging, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App with DI so I introduced a Startup.cs class. In that class, I added a logger and can see log entries in the Output window in Visual Studio. But I am not seeing the logs in App Insights.

Start.cs

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(EventSubscriberWithAutoAuthFunc.Startup))]
namespace EventSubscriberWithAutoAuthFunc
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {        
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            ConfigureServices(builder);                            
            builder.Services.AddLogging();

            var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddApplicationInsights());
            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
            logger.LogInformation("startup.cs Configure");            
        }        

        public void ConfigureServices(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I can see the logs in the Debug Output window:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"AppTraces","time":"2021-08-12T17:38:12.9503069Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"8901-FFPJNF2.KMX.LOCAL","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"il:2.14.0-17971"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"startup.cs Configure","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"startup.cs Configure","CategoryName":"Startup"}}}}
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace",
      "Host.Results": "Trace",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I searched in App Insights in the `traces` table without success. I have also tried [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp#setting-up) that adds a Diagnostic Setting and writes to a `FunctionAppLogs` in Log Analytics. I was hoping to find the logs for CategoryName = "Startup" but nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you see the caveats section of [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#caveats) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Insights added in Azure Function automatically, so check on [Log Telemetry in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#log-custom-telemetry-in-c-functions) and see differences of function Specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I can use this approach to log to the customEvents table in App Insights!